# For each unique occurrence in field, print sum corresponding numerical field and number of occurrences/counts

Tags: awk

I have a file

```
a       x       0   3
a       x       0   1
b,c     x       4   4
dd      x       3   5
dd      x       2   5
e,e,t   x       5   7
a       b       1   9
cc      b       2   1
cc      b       1   1
e,e,t   b       1   2
e,e,t   b       1   2
e,e,t   b       1   2
```

for each element in `$1$2`, I want print the sum `$3, $4` and the number of occurrences/lenght/counts

So that I have

```
a       x       0   4   0   2
b,c     x       4   4   1   1
dd      x       5   10  2   2
e,e,t   x       5   7   1   1
a       b       1   9   1   1
cc      b       3   2   2   2   
e,e,t   b       3   6   3   3
```

I am using

```
awk -F"\t" '{for(n=2;n<=NF; ++n) a[$1 OFS $2][n]+=$n}
        END {for(i in a) {
                printf "%s", i
                for (n=3; n<=4; ++n) printf "\t%s", a[i][n], a[i][n]++
                printf "\n" }}' file
```

but it's only printing the sums, not the counts

The actual file has many columns: the keys are `$4$6$7$8` and the numerical columns are `$9-$13`

Comment: But your input file has only 4 column so not sure how are you using `$5,$6,$7,$8` etc

Comment: The actual file is much more complicated. The keys are in $4 $6 $7 $8 and the numerical columns are $9 $10 $11 $12 $13. The example is a simplified test file for here. I'm happy with help using the simplified file. I can modify for the corresponding in the actual file.

Comment: Can you please make your sample input, expected output, and textual description all align? There is no column 5 to sum up, for example. And how do you get the totals for `dd x` that you do when there's only one such line in the input?

Comment: Your code is still using $4 through $8 and your text still says `the keys are $4$6$7$8 and the numerical columns are $9-$13`. The clearer and simpler your question the better chance you'll get a good answer. It doesn't matter to use what your real data does, just the example you provide us. Mapping the solution to the problem you post here to your real data is what you do afterwards.

Comment: Not sure where you trying to point to... It's correct here '{for(n=8;n<=NF; ++n) a[$4 OFS $6 OFS $7 OFS $8][n]+=$n}

Comment: Your posted sample input has 4 fields, e.g. `a       x       0   3`. Your code `for(n=8;n<=NF; ++n)` starts at field 8 which doesn't exist in that input, and your text says `the keys are $4$6$7$8` when field 6 and beyond don't exist in that input. You provided sample input with 4 columns so show us code that tries to use those 4 columns and provide explanatory text that only talks about those 4 columns. Anything else, no matter how accurately it applies to your real world data, just muddies **this question**.

Comment: Yeah, that was the code I was using with the original file, for which $4$6$7$8 are the keys and $9,$10$11,$12,$13 are numerical. I've updated the code to correspond to the test file instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
cat sum.awk

BEGIN {
   FS = OFS = "\t"     # set input/output FS to tab 
}
{
   k = $1 OFS $2       # create key using $1 tab $2
   if (!(k in map3))   # if k is not in map3 save it in an ordered array
      ord[++n] = k

   map3[k] += $3       # sum of $3 in array map3 using key as k
   $3 > 0 && ++fq3[k]  # frequency of $3 if it is > 0
   map4[k] += $4       # sum of $4 in array map4 using key as k
   $4 > 0 && ++fq4[k]  # frequency of $4 if it is > 0
}
END {
   for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) # print everything by looping through ord array
      print ord[i], map3[ord[i]], map4[ord[i]], fq3[ord[i]]+0, fq4[ord[i]]+0
}
```

Then use it as:

```sh
awk -f sum.awk file

a       x   0   4   0   2
b,c     x   4   4   1   1
dd      x   5   10  2   2
e,e,t   x   5   7   1   1
a       b   1   9   1   1
cc      b   3   2   2   2
e,e,t   b   3   6   3   3
```

Comment: Thank you for the nicely commented code. I guess the only issue I'm running into with it, is when the input file has 0s and the sum is also 0, I would want to also have 0 printed in the counts. Currently it's leaving the field blank. I've edited my sample to include 0s.

Comment: Would I have to do <$3 > 0 ? ++fq3[k] : 0> ?